# Prove that $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ $\ $(mod $p$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Consider the equivalence relation $m\sim n$ defined to be $\frac {m-n}p=z$ (i.e., when $m-n$ is divisible by p) where $m,n,p,z\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $p$ is prime.  Now suppose that $a$ is some integer not divisible by $p$.  Prove that $[a]^{p-1}=[1]$ where [1] denotes the equivalence class of 1.  Another common way to write this is $a^{p-1} \equiv 1$ $\ $(mod $p$).

I understand that there is some intent to prove multiplicative inverses here, but I'm a bit confused as to how one would approach it.

Comment: hint: In a group $a^{|G|} = e$ $\ $ for every a in G where $|G|$ is the order of the group and $e$ is the identity.

Comment: My favorite proof is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Second_method

Comment: This was never asked before?

Comment: @hardmath: And note that this is a very rare answer by B.D. that actually uses italics for variables (at least in the quote).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen: The new duplicate question process seems to have a side effect of removing a comment (pointing to an earlier Q) when the banner is added.  In a couple of cases, as here, my comment was slightly more substantive than just a link to the dup, so I'm not entirely happy with the change.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint 1:** Consider the group $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^{\times}\cong U_{p}$

**Hint 2:** $\varphi(p)=p-1$ where $\varphi$ is Euler's totient function and $p$ is a prime number

Comment: So I'm trying to prove Euler's theorem to get Euler's totient function?  I'm not very advanced in my subject, but I think this is what you mean.

Comment: No. mu suggestion is to use the other hint given to you in the first comment. I assume that all three hints are known to you

Comment: Oh well, no, I'm fairly new at these things and it's not completely clear to me how to make sense of it, but thanks.

Comment: @Casquibaldo: The nonzero elements of $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ form a multiplicative group with $p-1$ elements. What does Cauchy's theorem tell us?

Comment: @hardmath - You only need Lagrange for this

Comment: @Belgi: Yes, you are right, thanks for the correction!